# haml with rails3 (git master) and devise: form_for syntax change breaks haml -- suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am trying to get haml working with a rails3 project; 
since i am quite far in the modeling i wanted to go to the haml views now --
seems that the current haml (git master) does not work together with the current rails3 git master because of some syntax changes in rails3 form_for

does anyone have more information on the syntax changes?
is there a temporary workaround to use haml with rails3? (i am on a deadline) :(

see also: http://groups.google.at/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/6e0b403769c47b8c?hl=de

thanks!

Comment: i also posted this issue on the haml list - see http://groups.google.at/group/haml/browse_thread/thread/98325c598f69b29f?hl=de

Comment: If this is for an app with a scheduled production release, I would consider using Rails 2.3.5. Rails 3 is in beta, subject to change and support is still lacking for many plugins and gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the just-released 2.2.21.

Answer (score 0):

for other people coming across this thread:
while the specific issue is resolved with the haml update, there are
still some rails issues around,
which you can see on the ticket i opened in the rails lighthouse
tracker: http://bit.ly/9pHjRA